# Is this function surjective، Injective or nether surjective nor surjective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm taking a course in discrete math
And I saw this question,

> f(x) = 2x² and f:Z to Z

Comment: What is the inverse image of $-2$?

Comment: in this function shouldn't it be 1 and -1 ?

Comment: 'found a lot of different answers of it.' like what?

'

Comment: What do you mean by "in this function shouldn't it be 1 and -1"?

Comment: What is "ne[i]ther surjective nor surjective" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets See.

Injective?
$f(a)=f(b)$

Counterexample: $f(2) = f(-2)$ but $2\not=-2$. Not injective.

Surjective?
$f(a)=b$

$2a^2 = b \iff a^2=\frac{b}{2} \iff a=\sqrt{\frac{b}{2}}$. Not Surjective. Can you see why?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't quite get how it's not surjective because "Every element in B has some A."  For example if we took the numbers 1 and -1 as inputs, then isn't the output should be 2 for both 1 & -1 ?

Comment: You seem to be confusing injective and surjective. If you take $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$, the output for both will indeed be $2$. Thus, $f(1)=f(-1)$. However, since $1 \not=-1$, the function is not injective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now I understand it.